# Convert date in state array back to Date object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I am saving state in my React app via localStorage

```
const [items, setItem] = useState(() => {
let itemsString = window.localStorage.getItem('items');
if (itemsString) {
  try {
    return JSON.parse(itemsString);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    return [];
  }
} else {
  return [];
}
})
```

when I `JSON.parse(itemsString)` the date in the state has been converted to UTC (because strings/localstorage)

How do I `JSON.parse()` my state and reinitialize the date string to an object?

e.g. instead of returning 2019-07-19T00:28:03.058Z return Thu Jul 18 2019 20:28:03 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) instead

**Solution I came up with the help of Aaron's suggestion below.**

Store old state. Map over state array, creating new empty object and storing each property in it, store date, convert date to string and pass that into new Date object to instantiate the value back to a date object on page refresh.

```
const [items, setItem] = useState(() => {
let itemsString = window.localStorage.getItem('items');
if (itemsString) {
  try {
    const oldState = JSON.parse(itemsString);
    const newState = oldState.map(item => {
      const date = item.date;
      const container = {} 
      container.id = item.id
      container.item = item.item
      container.date = new Date(date.toString())
      container.cost = item.cost
      container.type = item.type
      return container;
    })

    return newState;
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    return [];
  }
} else {
  return [];
}
})
```

Answer (score 1):

After you parse `itemString` just set the date key to a new Date object

```
const object = JSON.parse(itemString);
const newState = {...object, date: new Date(object.date)}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work, it crashes my app initially and I have to clear my site data. 

Once I do that and rerun my state is not applied at all after refresh.

For reference the implementation I tried was

`try {
   const object = JSON.parse(itemsString);
   const newState = {...object, date: new Date(object.date)}
   return newState
  }`

Comment: What does the structure of the data? You will need to adjust depending on that. I don't know what object looks like after you parse it.

Comment: `JSON.parse(itemsString)` might return something like `[{…}]
0: {id: "2019-07-19T01:45:29.929Z", item: "Couch", date: "2019-07-19T01:45:21.376Z", cost: "78", type: "expense"}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)`

Comment: Got it. Then loop over each object in the array and re-set the date like I did above.